# Simple Unity character controller problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making 2D platformer and to make character move i use this
void Update()

```
{
move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);
}
```

but when i tried to make dashing mechanic by adding X force it just ignored it because X velocity is always fixed...
What should i do?

I tried this

```
Vector2 input = new Vector2(move*speed, 0)
rb.velocity += input;
```

and

```
rb.velocity * input;
```

and many others.. nothing helped..

Comment: Simply make your dash overrule the `move.x` ? Makes little sense to mix forces and setting velocity...

Answer (score 0):

Update is called every frame, so adding lots of force for one frame isnt going to do much, heres much better way to do this.
Start by making some variables:

```
private bool dashing = false;
private float dashTimer = 0;
private int dashDirection;
private float dashCooldownTimer = 0;
public float dashDuration = 0.5f;
public float dashCooldown = 1f;
public float dashForce = 8f;

public float moveSpeed = 5f;
// assign x input to a variable so it can be accessed anywhere in the script.
private float xInput;
```

Now you need a way to set the players current direction, I'm assuming your using a script that flips the player with its x scale, you can add create this new function and add it to the update:

```
// add this to the top of the update function
void Update() {
    // check if the scale is bigger or smaller than 0 and assign the direction.
    if (transform.localScale > 0) {
        dashDirection = 1;
    }
    else if (transform.localScale < 0) {
        dashDirection = -1;
    }
}
```

Note: if your flipping the player a different way, let me know as this wont work.
Now we need to check if the players dashing, so you can add this below our previous code:

```
// add this to the top of the update function
void Update() {
    // check if the scale is bigger or smaller than 0 and assign the direction.
    if (transform.localScale > 0) {
        dashDirection = 1;
    }
    else if (transform.localScale < 0) {
        dashDirection = -1;
    }

    // for this example I check whether the shift key is pressed, but you can change this depending on what you want to make the player dash, also check if the cooldown has finished
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dashCooldownTimer <= 0) {
        dashCooldownTimer = dashCooldown;
        dashing = true;
        dashTimer = 0;
    }
}
```

Now that the dash checker is complete, we just need to implement the dash, to do so, you can add this code into `FixedUpdate()`:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    if (dashing && dashTimer >= 0) {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dashForce * dashDirection, 0);
    }
    if (dashing && dashTimer < dashDuration) {
        dashTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else {
        dashing = false;
        dashTimer = 0;
    }
    if (dashCooldownTimer > 0) {
        dCooldown -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to only apply movement when were not dashing, otherwise you will get a jittering effect.

```
// add this to the top of the update function
void Update() {
    // check if the scale is bigger or smaller than 0 and assign the direction.
    if (transform.localScale > 0) {
        dashDirection = 1;
    }
    else if (transform.localScale < 0) {
        dashDirection = -1;
    }

    // for this example I check whether the shift key is pressed, but you can change this depending on what you want to make the player dash, also check if the cooldown has finished
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dashCooldownTimer <= 0) {
        dashCooldownTimer = dashCooldown;
        dashing = true;
        dashTimer = 0;
    }

    xInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if (!dashing) rb.velocity = new Vector2(xInput * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
}
```

This should work fine, but yes, dashes are way more complicated than they look. Let me know if you need any help :)